# set default value in magento 2.4

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm working on Magento 2.4 and I was creating a custom field in system.xml. I want to set the default value of this field as the URL of the store. How can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set the default value of custom field. For this create a below file in your module folder.

```
etc/config.xml
```

and add below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
            <default>
                 <sectionId>
                     <groupId>
                         <fieldId>default_value_store_url</fieldId>
                     </groupId>
                 </sectionId>
             </default>
    </config>
```

The sectionId/groupId/fieldId has to match the structure in the system.xml file.

Clear cache and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create config.xml in etc folder of module and we can configure default value as in below example

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <storeCode>
        <sectionid>
            <groupid>
                <fieldname></fieldname>
            </groupid>
        </sectionid>
    </storeCode>
</config>
```

to set the default value on store level need to change "storeCode" otherwise we can use "default"